# How to manage virtual Ethernet interface (NDIS) with cmd

Tags: networking, windows-8, android, tethering

I frequently use the usb tethering function of my android smartphone. If the network manager establishes the connection, the network gets almost every time a new Network name (started with "Network 1" it increments the number after "Network" every time).

I suspect the Smartphone uses another mac address for the virtual Ethernet device each time, it starts the virtual device, or boots the OS or whatever. I have not enough knowledge about the used technology to say it definitely.

It would be OK for me, if i could just delete the old networks one and again. I thought, I can delete them with the `netsh lan` command, but the result is only the following

```
C:\Windows\system32> netsh lan show profiles
The Wired AutoConfi Service (dot3svc) is not running
```

So i started it with:

```
C:\Windows\system32> sc.exe config dot3svc start= auto
```

After this the command `netsh lan show interface` shows my hardware Ethernet interface (Realtek PCIe) but not the virtual one. `netsh int show int` lists it though (It is in german):

```
C:\Windows\system32>netsh int show int

Verw.-status   Status         Typ              Schnittstellenname
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Deaktiviert    Getrennt       Dediziert        WiFi
Aktiviert      Verbunden      Dediziert        Ethernet 2
Aktiviert      Getrennt       Dediziert        Ethernet
```

The virtual Ethernet device prints the name `SAMSUNG Mobile USB Remote NDIS Network Device`. How can i control the NDIS device via command line? (Graphically would be OK either, if it is possible)

Answer (score 0):

List command:

```
C:\Windows\system32>netsh mbn show interfaces
```

Connect command:

```
C:\Windows\system32>netsh mbn connect interface="interface_name" connmode=name name="connection_name"
```

Disconnect command:

```
C:\Windows\system32>netsh mbn disconnect interface="interface_name"
```